# Testing site with login access AND login inside

Tags: users, 6, testing

I know it is counterintuitive, but I need to make my testing site secure and within it I need to test the user login module, so apparently I would be needing two login modules.

Is there a module that allows me to have two separate login systems? The "outer" one could be different from the "inner" one, of course. The "outer" one would only be for accessing a subdomain. The "inner" one would deal with user names and passwords.

Any idea and suggestions are welcome.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Secure Site](http://drupal.org/project/securesite) module. This module allows you to authenticate users with a browser-based password (HTTP Auth). Giving you the "outer" authentication layer. Then use Drupal core's login for the "inner".

Comment: Great! Thanx Nicoz, looks like this will do the trick. :)

Comment: Does this protect files that don't get served up from Drupal?  Things like images, PDFs, CSS, JS.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on your question.

Comment: Normally when you do .htaccess style protection to implement HTTP Auth, everything in the directory tree requires HTTP Auth.  It isn't clear in the docs whether  you can have this module enabled, and be able to bypass the auth and access files, eg sites/files/whatever/foo.jpg

Comment: Gotcha now. Not sure if it does. I never considered it. It feels like forever since I have built a D6 site and I don't have any hanging around anymore to do some testing (All D7 now). I think your going to have to try it out and see.